# Broken alignment with systeme and babel

Tags: babel, systeme

When I add a `babel` package with option `czech`, the alignment of systeme gets broken.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}

\begin{document}
$$
\systeme{x+2y = 0, x-y = -1}
$$
\end{document}
```

The results is:

[image: wrong alignment]

Without the option or when changing `czech` to `english`, this example works as expected (i.e., variables aligned). Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Try `\shorthandoff{-}` before the equation (if you need `czech`'s special meaning of `-` you should add `\shorthandon{-}` after the equation or use `\begingroup...\endgroup` around the equation to keep the effect local). Note that `\[...\]` is preferred over `$$...$$` in LaTeX

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `czech` language module for `babel` makes the hyphen character `-` an active shorthand, which means that some uses of `-` break or don't work as expected.

You can temporarily disable this special meaning of `-` with `\shorthandoff`, to keep the effect of this command local, we add `\begingroup...\endgroup` around the equation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\shorthandoff{-}
\[
  \systeme{x+2y = 0, x-y = -1}
\]
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image: System of equations with expected alignment.]

Since `\[...\]` comes with a grouping of its own,

```
\[
  \shorthandoff{-}
  \systeme{x+2y = 0, x-y = -1}
\]
```

also works (thanks to [@egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) for [pointing that out in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/533503/broken-alignment-with-systeme-and-babel/533505?noredirect=1#comment1349219_533505)).

Another option would be to use no grouping and explicitly turn the shorthand back on

```
\shorthandoff{-}
\[
  \systeme{x+2y = 0, x-y = -1}
\]
\shorthandon{-}
```

---

Note that in LaTeX `\[...\]` is preferable over `$$...$$`, see [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/35864).

Comment: Why not `\shorthandoff` *after* `\[`? For a one-line display it's surely easier.

Comment: @egreg Because I didn't think to check whether or not `\[...\]` introduces a group. Thanks for the hint. Will edit in a sec.